# How to create custom Shopify ajax Filter for collection?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api, shopify-activemerchant

I am beginner to Shopify. I want to use the ajax filter for Shopify collection page. I want to select multiple filter using checkbox for tag, type , variant , price.
I want filter similar like this https://teamlocker.squadlocker.com/#/browse?_k=70vphy

I found few paid app also but i want to use custom code in default Shopify theme i.e Debut

Please guide me is it possible or or not?

Thanks

Comment: Shopify filters accept only tags. You'll need to implement a frontend filter or use an app for this.

Comment: I have variant colors and price how i can implement that in tag ?

Comment: Variant colours can be added as tags for the products manually, but prices cannot. It'll be too cumbersome to manage. If we are talking about less than 250 products you can do this via frontend without an app. If it is more then you'll need an external system to maintain the products listing and the filters outside Shopify.

Comment: External system mean need to develop app?

Comment: That or use something in the market